# VS code is set to work with python 2.7, how can one change it to 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[image: Invalid Syntax on valid pyhton 3 syntax]

Hello all, have just started to use vs code for python. I am using python version 3.8. I have installed python extension which helps with syntax completion but its giving suggestions according python 2.7 and gives error where new syntax included in python 3 is used.
Can you direct me which settings are needed to be updated?

```
def fibonacci_series(lim):
    print("-- Fibonacci Series --")
    a=b=1
    for x in range(0, lim):
        yield a
        a,b = b,a+b

def main():
    for x in fibonacci_series(5):
        print(x , end=" ") # <- vs code says this is invalid syntax, but still runs it successfully.
    print()

main()
```

I have settings.json as this.

**settings.json**

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/bin/pylint",
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3.8",
    "code-runner.executorMap": 
    { 
        "python": "python3.8 -u" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of your code is the syntax error for?

Comment: ```print(" ", end=" ")``` , this part is giving invalid error. I can run this successfully in terminal. But VS code prompts that this is an error. I think somewhere it is set to pyhton 2.7, I don't exactly know where is it.

Comment: Difficult to give any solid answer because you have posted a screenshot instead of actual code. Try `print " ",`. If that works then you are using python 2.7 otherwise, `print(" ", end=" ")` is not the problem

Comment: Hi @smac89, I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. All I can suggest is to make sure you are using the right indentation and check above that line for any potential sources of the syntax error

Comment: I suggest you try to get a newer extension pack. That may be what's causing the error.

Comment: **pylint** gives you this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from Pylint. Did you specify a globally installed copy of Pylint via `python.lintings.pytlintPath`? If so and it's installed via Python 2.7 that would explain your issue. I would create a virtual environment for your project and install Pylint into the virtual environment to make sure it is being run for the version of Python you expect.

Comment: Thank You [@Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236574/brett-cannon)
It worked. Yay! In ubuntu 18.04 `python` is pointing to `python 2.7`. For `python 3.x`, we have to use 'python3' or whichever custom version installed.
So to install python3 pylint I had to use 'python3 -m pip install pylint' and then give the path in setting.json' in vs code.